# calendar code worked in activity but not in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, calendar, fragment

I wrote a code in an Activity class that used Calendar, and then I moved it to Fragment, and I am attaching this fragment to Activity dynamically, by calling:`

```
mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        //mButtonsFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_buttons);
        mLayout1to6 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_1to6);
        final FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.fragment_1to6, f1to6);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        mFragmentManager
                .addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        setLayout();
                    }
                });


        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
`
```

and Fragment code itself is this:

```
public class Fragment_1to6 extends Fragment {
    private Activity mActivity;

    Calendar calendar;
    String month_name;

    TextView month1;
    TextView month2;
    TextView month3;
    TextView month4;
    TextView month5;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1to6, container, false);
        month1 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView1);
        month2 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView2);
        month3 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView3);
        month4 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView5);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setMonths();

            return view;

        }
    public void setCurrentMonthName() {

        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month_name = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
        month1.setText(month_name);
    }


    protected void getNextMonth(int i) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                month2.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                break;
            case 2:
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                month3.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                break;
            case 3:
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                month4.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                break;
            case 4:
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                month5.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                break;
        }

    }
    public void setMonths() {
        setCurrentMonthName();
        getNextMonth(1);
        getNextMonth(2);
        getNextMonth(3);
        getNextMonth(4);
    }


}
`
```

However, when I run it, it gives NullPointerException on the line where I setText on textViews, saying that it cannot setText on a Null Object Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code

```
month1 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView1);
month2 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView2);
month3 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView3);
month4 = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.monthView5);
```

with

```
month1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthView1);
month2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthView2);
month3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthView3);
month4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthView5);
```

Activity is where you are inflating your fragment on it. But all the TextViews are part of fragment xml and you have to access them from fragment's view, not from activity's view.

Comment: Thanks! I also changed FrameLayout to fragment in xml